# homestead - This webpage is not available

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualization, homestead

I do not know where I got stuck, I used already homestead and can not figure out the problem. The virtual machine runs correctly, folders are also mirrored correctly.

```
$ vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8000 (adapter 1)
    default: 443 => 44300 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 33060 (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 => 54320 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/Roko/Homestead
    default: /home/vagrant/Code => C:/Users/Roko/Homestead/Code
    default: /home/vagrant/Code/geogram => C:/Users/Roko/Homestead/Code/geogram
    default: /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin => C:/Users/Roko/Homestead/Code/phpmyadmin
    default: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public => C:/Users/Roko/Homestead/Code/Laravel/public
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

I added entries to the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1  phpmyadmin.app
127.0.0.1  homestead.app
```

and this is YAML file:

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 1048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Homestead/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code


sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

    - map: phpmyadmin.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin/


databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

And I still get This web page is not available for http://homestead.app:8000/
Can someone figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing you hosts file to `192.168.10.10  phpmyadmin.app
192.168.10.10  homestead.app`

Comment: I tried that also, but result is same

Comment: Try re-provisioning your homestead using the `homestead provision` command or `vagrant provision`. Then try and access them.

Comment: Nothing, again webpage is not available. Just one note i can ping 192.186.10.10 and http:// 127.0.0.1:2222/ give me (SSH-2.0 OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 Protocol mismatch.)

Comment: I tried using incognito mode and it worked. Maybe it failed because of caching. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried `vagrant reload --provision`

Answer (score 0):

Your vagrant up and the Homestead.yaml configruation is fine. But the ip address inside your hosts file should be 192.168.10.10 so to resolve this edit the hosts file acordingly
(read documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead)

```
192.168.10.10 phpmyadmin.app
192.168.10.10 homestead.app
```

then reload your vagrant using provision

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

That should do it.

Answer (score -1):

use 192.168.10.10 in your /etc/hosts
Example..
192.168.10.10 Laravel.app